# Study correlation in case of nonlinearity

Tags: correlation, pearson-r, spearman-rho

[image]

Looking at the graph, clearly there is a correlation between the $x$ and $y$ values. However, this correlation is not linear, hence it cannot be studied by the `pearson correlation coefficient`.

I know there is the `Spearman rank correlation coefficient`, however this coefficient studies whether $x$ increases whenever $y$ increases. But in my case, let's say for $y = 0$, $x$ is increasing. So again, this correlation cannot be studied by the `spearman` correlation coefficient.
What is the best way to quantify this correlation?

Plus, I'd appreciate to ways to do it in `python`.

Comment: There's a discussion in this thread of the many approaches to nonlinear dependence structures... http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179511/why-zero-correlation-does-not-necessarily-imply-independence/179551#179551

Answer (score 2):

A good measure of dependence is the distance correlation coefficient.
It allows to measure many kinds of relations. Thus you can try it on your data.

In R, there is a procedure named "`dcor`" within the package "`energy`" to compute this coefficient.

In Python, here is an implementation of this coefficient : https://gist.github.com/josef-pkt/2938402