# Does covariance equal to zero implies independence for binary random variables?

Tags: covariance, independence

If $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables that can only take two possible states, how can I show that $Cov(X,Y) = 0$ implies independence? This kind of goes against what I learned back in the day that $Cov(X,Y) = 0$ does not imply independence...

The hint says to start with $1$ and $0$ as the possible states and generalize from there. And I can do that and show $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$, but this doesn't imply independence???

Kind of confused how to do this mathematically I guess.

Comment: It is not true in general as your question's heading suggests..

Comment: The statement that you are trying to prove is indeed true. If $X$ and $Y$ are Bernoulli random variables wot parameters $p_1$ and $p_2$ respectively, then $E[X]=p_1$ and $E[Y]=p_2$. So, $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)=E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]$ equals $0$ only if $E[XY]=P\{X=1,Y=1\}$ equals $p_1p_2=P\{X=1\}P\{Y=1\}$ showing that $\{X=1\}$ and $\{Y=1\}$ are _independent_ **events**. It is a standard result that if $A$ and $B$ are a pair of independent events, then so are $A,B^c$, and $A^c,B$, and $A^c,B^c$ independent  events, i.e. $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables. Now generalize.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For binary variables their expected value equals the probability that they are equal to one. Therefore,

$$ E(XY) = P(XY = 1) = P(X=1 \cap Y=1) \\ 
E(X) = P(X=1) \\ 
E(Y) = P(Y=1) \\
$$

If the two have zero covariance this means $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$, which means

$$ P(X=1 \cap Y=1) = P(X=1) \cdot P(Y=1) $$

It is trivial to see all other joint probabilities multiply as well, using the basic rules about independent events (i.e. if $A$ and $B$ are independent then their complements are independent, etc.), which means the joint mass function factorizes, which is the definition of two random variables being independent.

Comment: Concise and elegant. Classy! +1 =D

Answer (score 9):

Both correlation and covariance measure linear association between two given variables and it has no obligation to detect any other form of association else.

So those two variables might be associated in several other non-linear ways and covariance (and, therefore, correlation) could not distinguish from independent case.

As a very didactic, artificial and non realistic example, one can consider $X$ such that $P(X=x)=1/3$ for $x=−1,0,1$ and also consider $Y=X^2$. Notice that they are not only associated, but one is a function of the other. Nonetheless, their covariance is 0, for their association is orthogonal to the association that covariance can detect.

EDIT

Indeed, as indicated by @whuber, the above original answer was actually a comment on how the assertion is not universally true if both variables were not necessarily dichotomous.  My bad!

So let's math up.  (The local equivalent of Barney Stinson's "Suit up!")

#### Particular Case

If both $X$ and $Y$ were dichotomous, then you can assume, without loss of generality, that both assume only the values $0$ and $1$ with arbitrary probabilities $p$, $q$ and $r$ given by
$$
\begin{align*}
P(X=1) = p \in [0,1] \\
P(Y=1) = q \in [0,1] \\
P(X=1,Y=1) = r \in [0,1],
\end{align*}
$$
which characterize completely the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$.
Taking on @DilipSarwate's hint, notice that those three values are enough to determine the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$, since
$$
\begin{align*}
P(X=0,Y=1) 
  &= P(Y=1) - P(X=1,Y=1) 
  = q - r\\
P(X=1,Y=0) 
  &= P(X=1) - P(X=1,Y=1) 
  = p - r\\
P(X=0,Y=0) 
  &= 1 - P(X=0,Y=1) - P(X=1,Y=0) - P(X=1,Y=1) \\
  &= 1 - (q - r) - (p - r) - r
  = 1 - p - q - r.
\end{align*}
$$
(On a side note, of course $r$ is bound to respect both $p-r\in[0,1]$, $q-r\in[0,1]$ and $1-p-q-r\in[0,1]$ beyond $r\in[0,1]$, which is to say $r\in[0,\min(p,q,1-p-q)]$.)

Notice that $r = P(X=1,Y=1)$ might be equal to the product $p\cdot q = P(X=1) P(Y=1)$, which would render $X$ and $Y$ independent, since 
$$
\begin{align*}
P(X=0,Y=0) 
  &= 1 - p - q - pq 
  = (1-p)(1-q) 
  = P(X=0)P(Y=0)\\
P(X=1,Y=0) 
  &= p - pq 
  = p(1-q) 
  = P(X=1)P(Y=0)\\
P(X=0,Y=1) 
  &= q - pq 
  = (1-p)q 
  = P(X=0)P(Y=1).
\end{align*}
$$

Yes, $r$ might be equal to $pq$, **BUT** it can be different, as long as it respects the boundaries above.

Well, from the above joint distribution, we would have
$$
\begin{align*}
E(X) 
  &= 0\cdot P(X=0) + 1\cdot P(X=1) 
  = P(X=1) 
  = p
\\
E(Y) 
  &= 0\cdot P(Y=0) + 1\cdot P(Y=1) 
  = P(Y=1) 
  = q
\\
E(XY) 
  &= 0\cdot P(XY=0) + 1\cdot P(XY=1) \\
  &= P(XY=1) 
  = P(X=1,Y=1) 
  = r\\
Cov(X,Y)
  &= E(XY) - E(X)E(Y) 
  = r - pq
\end{align*}
$$

Now, notice then that $X$ and $Y$ are independent **if and only if** $Cov(X,Y)=0$.  Indeed, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $P(X=1,Y=1)=P(X=1)P(Y=1)$, which is to say $r=pq$.  Therefore, $Cov(X,Y)=r-pq=0$; and, on the other hand, if $Cov(X,Y)=0$, then $r-pq=0$, which is to say $r=pq$.  Therefore, $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

#### General Case

About the *without loss of generality* clause above, if $X$ and $Y$ were distributed otherwise, let's say, for $a<b$ and $c<d$,
$$
\begin{align*}
P(X=b)=p \\
P(Y=d)=q \\
P(X=b, Y=d)=r
\end{align*}
$$
then $X'$ and $Y'$ given by
$$
X'=\frac{X-a}{b-a} 
\qquad
\text{and}
\qquad
Y'=\frac{Y-c}{d-c}
$$
would be distributed just as characterized above, since
$$
X=a \Leftrightarrow X'=0, \quad
X=b \Leftrightarrow X'=1, \quad
Y=c \Leftrightarrow Y'=0  \quad
\text{and} \quad
Y=d \Leftrightarrow Y'=1.
$$
So $X$ and $Y$ are independent **if and only if** $X'$ and $Y'$ are independent.

Also, we would have
$$
\begin{align*}
E(X') 
  &= E\left(\frac{X-a}{b-a}\right) 
  = \frac{E(X)-a}{b-a} \\
E(Y') 
  &= E\left(\frac{Y-c}{d-c}\right) 
  = \frac{E(Y)-c}{d-c} \\
E(X'Y') 
  &= E\left(\frac{X-a}{b-a} \frac{Y-c}{d-c}\right) 
  = \frac{E[(X-a)(Y-c)]}{(b-a)(d-c)} \\
  &= \frac{E(XY-Xc-aY+ac)}{(b-a)(d-c)} 
  = \frac{E(XY)-cE(X)-aE(Y)+ac}{(b-a)(d-c)} \\
Cov(X',Y')
  &= E(X'Y')-E(X')E(Y') \\
  &= \frac{E(XY)-cE(X)-aE(Y)+ac}{(b-a)(d-c)}
    - \frac{E(X)-a}{b-a}
      \frac{E(Y)-c}{d-c} \\
  &= \frac{[E(XY)-cE(X)-aE(Y)+ac] - [E(X)-a] [E(Y)-c]}{(b-a)(d-c)}\\
  &= \frac{[E(XY)-cE(X)-aE(Y)+ac] - [E(X)E(Y)-cE(X)-aE(Y)+ac]}{(b-a)(d-c)}\\
  &= \frac{E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)}{(b-a)(d-c)} 
  = \frac{1}{(b-a)(d-c)} Cov(X,Y).
\end{align*}
$$
So $Cov(X,Y)=0$ **if and only** $Cov(X',Y')=0$.

=D

Comment: I recycled that answer from [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179511/why-zero-correlation-does-not-necessarily-imply-independence/179537#179537).

Comment: Verbatim cut and paste from your other post. Love it. +1

Comment: The problem with copy-and-paste is that your answer no longer seems to address the question: it is merely a comment on the question.  It would be better, then, to post a comment with a link to your other answer.

Comment: True, @whuber. I'm going to edit it.

Comment: How is thus an answer to the question asked?

Comment: Yes, @DilipSarwate, it was a lame of me, sorry.  I hope I have mended it.  =D

Comment: Your edits _still_ don't answer the question, at least not at the level the question is asked. You write "Notice that $r~\ldots$ not necessarily equal to the product $pq$. That exceptional situation corresponds to the case of independence between $X$ and $Y$." which is a perfectly true statement but only for the _cognoscenti_ because for the _hoi polloi_, independence requires not just that $$P(X=1,Y=1)=P(X=1)P(Y=1)\tag 1$$ but also $$P(X=u,Y=v)=P(X=u)P(Y=v),~u.v\in\{0,1\}.\tag 2$$ Yes, $(1) \implies(2)$ as the _cognoscenti know_; for lesser mortals, a proof that $(1) \implies (2)$ is helpful.

Comment: True, @DilipSarwate. Gonna address it.  Thank you.

Comment: OK, I have removed my downvote.  An additional suggestion: the bilinearity of the covariance operator gives $cov(a+bX,c+dY) = bd\cdot cov(X,Y)$ so that $a+bX$ and $c+dY$ have zero covariance if $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated. Also, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then so are $g(X)$ and $h(Y)$; in particular, $a+bX$ and $c+dY$ are independent. All this holds for arbitrary (not necessarily dichotomous) random variables. For dichotomous uncorrelated $X$ and $Y$, your proof of what I called $(1) \implies (2)$ earlier applies _mutatis mutandis_ to show that $a+bX$ and $c+dY$ are independent.