# Why are two random variables independent if the Pearson's correlation coefficient equals zero, but the same result does not hold for covariance?

Tags: correlation, covariance

I was reading the following book

> Han J, Pei J, Kamber M. Data mining: concepts and techniques.
>   Elsevier; 2011 Jun 9. (Third Edition)

On page 96, at the first line of the last paragraph it says ([here](https://books.google.com/books?id=pQws07tdpjoC&lpg=PA266&dq=han%20data%20mining%20If%20the%20resulting%20value%20is%20equal%20to&pg=PA96#v=onepage&q&f=false))

> If the resulting value is equal to $0$, then $A$ and $B$ are *independent* and there is no correlation between them.

where *the resulting value* above corresponds to the following formula (correlation coefficient)

$$
r_{A,B}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i - \overline{A}) (b_i - \overline{B})}{n\sigma_A\sigma_B}. \tag{3.3}
$$

However, on the next page on the last paragraph, it says

> If $A$ and $B$ are independent (i.e., they do not have correlation), then ... $Cov(A,B) = \ldots = 0$.

Up to here, everything looks good, however by the following relation 
$$
r_{A,B} = \frac{Cov(A,B)}{\sigma_A\sigma_B} \tag{3.5}
$$
the correlation and covariance are related and as far as I remember, if the covariance of two random variables tend to be zero, it is not necessary that they are independent. However, the book says if $r_{A,B} = 0$ , then $A$ and $B$ are independent. Am I right that the book is wrong? or there is something else happening here.

Comment: When all the correlations are 0 it is the off diagonal elements that should be 0. Zero correlation implies independence for a bivariate normal but not in general for other distrbutions.

Comment: Did you buy this book because it's required for a class? I can't think of other reasons to buy this thing

Comment: @Aksakal yes. it is required for a course.

Comment: If you read just a little further in the book, it explicitly tells you that zero covariance *does not* imply independence: see the bottom of p. 97.

Comment: @whuber you are right and the contradiction happens here. the $cov(a,b)=0$ does not imply independence, however, $r_{a,b}=0$ implies that. This is what the book says and is a contradiction.

Comment: I will wholeheartedly agree that the book is not well written.

Comment: sometimes this whole textbook publishing business looks like a collusion between the publishers and educators: the former pays the latter to force their product on students. some of these textbooks are awful, and would never survive without being required reads. then you have these countless editions of textbooks and the professors requiring the latest editions. why would anyone need 13th edition of calculus text? the damn thing hasn't changed in past 100 years

Comment: Please see the following thread: [Simple examples of uncorrelated but not independent $X$
and $Y$](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85363); I believe it will be a constructive addition to your understanding of the issue.

Comment: See [this question and its answers](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/261377/6633) for more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Under what additional conditions does independence follow from zero correlation?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261377/under-what-additional-conditions-does-independence-follow-from-zero-correlation)

Comment: Did you get a chance to lookup the book's errata?

Comment: @dangiankit yes, I have checked it out (here)[https://wiki.illinois.edu//wiki/display/cs591han/Errata+of+Data+Mining+(3rd+Edition)].

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Zero correlation does not imply independence. Either:

1. There is a typo/mistake and the book is wrong or
2. The book made additional assumptions previously, for example, that the joint distribution of A and B were bivariate normal.  There exist additional conditions such that zero correlation *and* these conditions would imply independence.

Comment: The first is true. there are no other assumptions made previously.

Answer (score 9):

Your book is wrong. Correlation zero is *not* a sufficient condition for independence. You *can* have Pearson correlation zero for variables that are *not* independent.

The independent variables will have both covariance and correlation zero, provided their variances are non-zero. There's no contradiction here.